# BigInteger bigger than the Long and Int?

Tags: c#, numbers, int, long-integer, biginteger

I am doing a program that will use very big numbers, and it will have too much work for even the slightest slow.
and my question is: is the big_integer slower than the normal int and long ?

```
    long number = 12;
    BigInteger number2 = 12;

public void add()
{
    number += 1;
}
public void add2()
{
    number2 += 1;
}
```

which one is faster now ?

Comment: Test it and find out.

Comment: Also - if your numbers will be larger than an Int64, you really don't have an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the type BigInteger slower than int or long.

But a BigInteger is *required* for integer calculations with really big numbers.